# The support of Gaussian measure in Hilbert Space $L^2(S^1)$ with covariance $(1-\Delta)^{-1}$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mu$ be Gaussian measure defined on Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}=L^2(S^1)$ ($S^1$ - circle) by formula 
$$
 \int e^{(f,g)} d\mu(f) = e^{-\tfrac{1}{2}(g,C g) }.
$$
The covariance operator $C$ is positive and trace-class. I wonder whether for some $C$ it might be possible to have $\mu(C(S^1))=1$ (C(S^1) - set of continuous functions on circle)? What are the conditions for $C$.

Let's consider the covariance $C=(1-\Delta)^{-1}$, where $\Delta$ - Laplace operator on the circle, $\Delta = \partial_\phi^2$. It is easy to check that $C$ is positive trace class operator. What might be said about the support of the measure $\mu$ in this case? Formally we can write "$d\mu(f) = \exp(-(f,C^{-1}f))df$", where $df$ is (not existing) Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal{H}$. The factor $\exp(-(f,C^{-1}f))$ vanishes for $f$ which are not sufficiently regular.

I suppose there should be some relation between the domain of $C^{-1}$ (it is necessarily unbounded operator because $C$ is trace class) and the support of the measure $\mu$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\mu(C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})) = 1$?

Comment: $\mu(C^\infty(\mathbb{R}))$ is the measure of the set of continuous functions. Because the considered measure is normalized $\mu(C^\infty(\mathbb{R}))=1$ means that $\mu(L^2(\mathbb{R})\setminus C^\infty(\mathbb{R}))=0$

Comment: That formula is wrong. On the LHS you have an integrated $f$ which pops out again in the right hand side.

Comment: I've corrected the typo.

Comment: You will probably find the answer in Bogachev's book.

Comment: @user72829 : Um, you don't have $C^{\infty}(\mathbb R) \subseteq L^2(\mathbb R)$ ; the function $f(x) = x$ is smooth but not integrable over the whole line. Do you mean the "smooth integrable functions" by $C^{\infty}(\mathbb R)$?

Comment: @Patric: Thanks for pointing this. I've changed $\mathbb{R}$ into $S^1$.

Comment: If you take a Fourier transform, it might be easier to find a Gaussian measure supported on an appropriate subspace of $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$.