# Expectation of $p$-norm under a Gaussian on the Hilbert space $L^2(S^1)$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory, probability-distributions, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mu$ be a centered Gaussian measure with (nondegenerate) covariance $Q$ on the  Hilbert space $L^2(S^1;\mathbb R)$  where $S^1$ is the circle. We can take for example the covariance $(1-\Delta)^{-1}$.

I would like to show that for every  $p=3,4,\dots$

$   I_p :=   \int \|f\|_p^p \mu (df)     \  <  \    \infty   $

where $\|f\|_p^p :=     \int |f(x)|^p   dx  \in [0,\infty]$.

In particular that $\|f\|_p^p<\infty $  a.s.

Note that this question is related to this

[The support of Gaussian measure in Hilbert Space $L^2(S^1)$ with covariance $(1-\Delta)^{-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/688824/the-support-of-gaussian-measure-in-hilbert-space-l2s1-with-covariance-1)

Note also that ($I_0=1$ and)    $I_2 = \text{Tr}   \   Q  <  \infty $.